# How does this range follow from this equation?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How does the range $0\leq i<\frac{n}{2}, \frac{n+1}{2}\leq i<n$ follow from $\left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor + \left \lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right \rfloor = n$?

The source where I read this from(page 2), in order to give some context to the question.

> https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4843

Comment: What is i?.........

Comment: ? there is no $i$ in your equation

Comment: Yes I know that, that's why I can't figure this out, and that's why I give the paper where I read this to see if someone can understand how the author connects these two things.

Comment: I think it doesn't follow. Simple as that. I don't see any reason to put the $<$ on the first range and the $\leq$ on the second range, rather than vice versa, just from considering the equation.

Answer (score 1):

In that paper, they deal with finding the middle of an array of length $n$, and the table they give summarizes the various expressions that best express the ***left half*** and ***right half*** of the array. As a mnemonic for the whole table, they are saying to remember the formula $\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor=n$.
What this probably means, is that you should (try to) split an array of length $n$
into a left half of length $\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$, and a right half of length $\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor$.

Because their arrays have indices from $0$ to $n-1$, that means the left half covers indices from index $0$, to the integer strictly smaller than $\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$, in other words every integer $i$,
$0\le i<\frac n2$. That gives you precisely $\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$
indices.

For the right half, using the mnemonic you'd go for the indices between $\frac{n+1}2$ until the end of the array, in other words every integer $i$,
$\frac{n+1}2\le i<n$. Note that when $n$ is odd, that range does **not** have
$\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor$ indices. But it is easy to remember the starting index of the right half from the stated equation.

As a somewhat more concrete exemple,
assume $n$ is odd, $n=2p+1$. You get $\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor=p$ and $\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor=p+1$. Using their left/right halves expressions:

- the left half ranges from $0$ to $p-1$ inclusive, for a total of $p$ indices
- the right half ranges from $p+1$ to $n-1$ inclusive, for a total of $p$ indices
- the index $p$ is left out from both halves, and is the central value of the array

Assuming that $n$ is even, $n=2p$, you get
$\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor=p=\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor$.

- the left half ranges from $0$ to $p-1$ inclusive, for a total of $p$ indices
- the right half ranges from $p$ to $n-1$ inclusive, for a total of $p$ indices
- there is no central value in the array